# Помогите найти ошибку

Tags: грамотная-речь

Знаю, что в этой фразе какой-то подвох, но не могу понять в чём именно: "*На словах все поддерживают старых ветеранов, а на деле – хотят лишить их последних льгот*."

Comment: Этой фразой вскрыт подвох.

Comment: Точку перенесите за закрывающие кавычки! А то мы будем думать, что это и есть подвох. А ветераны могут быть как старыми, так и молодыми.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, словосочетание "старый ветеран" можно посчитать плеоназмом (речевым излишеством). Впрочем, некоторые считают это тавтологией, образованной от соединения русского слова с иноязычным, дублирующего его значение. (https://studfiles.net/preview/1608875/page:15/)

Тире явно не обязательно здесь, но ошибкой не является.